# Какой язык использовать для пакетного редактирования Excel(xls)?

Tags: java, excel

На каком языке можно считать шаблон Excel(xls) отредактировать ячейку, и сохранить в новом файле?

Comment: Почти на любом.

Comment: Можно пример с сохранением структуры?

Comment: На Q&A-сервисах, типа SO, не пишут код за вас. Все необходимые примеры есть в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку Java `apache poi` для работы с excel файлами. Она позволяет:

*считать шаблон Excel(xls) отредактировать ячейку, и сохранить в новом файле*